# Django: TypeError: Object of type ModelBase is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django

I get Error 'TypeError: Object of type ModelBase is not JSON serializable'.

But i don't use JSON. And i don't put any 'ModelBase' object to templates.

It's started when i began to use `request.session` for global variables store. When i used global variables like in pure Python - this project worked ok. (On local developer server, but was a problem with works on deploy for multiuser load.)

I can't understand where it problem is appears:
I use Debug mode - my views.py function is runned proprly, it return `exit_` for temlate:

```
def page_Category_Main(request, cat_):
    #...
    
        exit_ = {
        'category_name':  category['category_name'], #str
        'categories_list': categories_list, #list
        'action': cat_, #str
        'tbl_ttx_col': [x for x in tab_marketability.keys() if x not in ['id', 'brand', 'name', 'price_avg', 
          'appear_month']], #list
        'tbl_data': tab_marketability, #dict
        'tbl_data_nov': tab_novelty, #dict
        'new_form': new_form, #dict
        'enabled': enabled_return, #list
        'checked_items': post_return, #list
        'period': request.session['period_mth_rus'], #list
        'tab_active': tab_active, #str
        'tab_list': list(dict_tabs.keys()), #list
        'tab_data': dict_tabs #dict
            }
        
        return render(request, template_name="al_category.html", context=exit_)
```

And server begin to handles template `al_category.html` (I see it in Python Debuger, becouse template use some `@register.filter` function from `views.py`).

And in unknown point raise this TypeError:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Nb/

Django Version: 3.1.2
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'marketability',
 'bootstrap4']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\ITResearch\all_gid_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\ITResearch\all_gid_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 116, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\User\ITResearch\all_gid_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py", line 63, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "C:\Users\User\ITResearch\all_gid_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 81, in save
    return self.create()
  File "C:\Users\User\ITResearch\all_gid_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 55, in create
    self.save(must_create=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\ITResearch\all_gid_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 83, in save
    obj = self.create_model_instance(data)
  File "C:\Users\User\ITResearch\all_gid_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 70, in create_model_instance
    session_data=self.encode(data),
  File "C:\Users\User\ITResearch\all_gid_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 116, in encode
    compress=True,
  File "C:\Users\User\ITResearch\all_gid_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 110, in dumps
    data = serializer().dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\User\ITResearch\all_gid_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 87, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

Exception Type: TypeError at /Nb/
Exception Value: Object of type ModelBase is not JSON serializable
```

What is matter?! What is the 'ModelBase Object'? I don't use any of it in template. I don't implement serialize of any object in my code... i don`t use JSON format where...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Django sessions use JSON serialization - see [**Session serialization**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization)

You can try to use `PickleSerializer`, set it in your **settings.py** - see [**SESSION_SERIALIZER**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-serializer):

```
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

Or write your own [**serializer**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#write-your-own-serializer):

> Note that unlike **PickleSerializer**, the **JSONSerializer** cannot handle
> arbitrary Python data types. As is often the case, there is a
> trade-off between convenience and security. If you wish to store more
> advanced data types including **datetime** and **Decimal** in JSON backed
> sessions, you will need to write a custom serializer (or convert such
> values to a JSON serializable object before storing them in
> **request.session**). While serializing these values is often
> straightforward (**DjangoJSONEncoder** may be helpful), writing a decoder
> that can reliably get back the same thing that you put in is more
> fragile. For example, you run the risk of returning a datetime that
> was actually a string that just happened to be in the same format
> chosen for **datetimes**).
>
> Your serializer class must implement two methods, **dumps(self, obj)** and
> **loads(self, data)**, to serialize and deserialize the dictionary of
> session data, respectively.